# C# low timer interval = slow drawtime?

Tags: c#, forms, timer, intervals, pong

I'm trying to make a simple pong game but I encountered this problem, each timer1 tick (with the interval set to 1ms) should move of 1 pixel the white paddle rectangle if the 'S' or 'W' button is pressed, this means theorically that the white rectangle inside my 400px in height picturebox should be moving from y = 0 to y = 400 in 0.4 - 0.8 seconds, but apparently it takes more than 4 full seconds.

I understand that timer tick events may be "skipped" if the cpu is already busy or by processing speed problems but I tried to make a snake game way more complex than these 50 lines of code and the speed of the drawn snake was actually accurate with low-time intervals

Why does it takes that much?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;

        timer1.Interval = 1;
        timer1.Start();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PongGame.CheckIfMoving();
        PongGame.DrawIt(pictureBox1);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.S)
        { PongGame.movesDown = true; }

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.W)
        { PongGame.movesUp = true; }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.S)
        { PongGame.movesDown = false; }

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.W)
        { PongGame.movesUp = false; }
    }
}



public class PongGame
{
    public static Rectangle paddle1 = new Rectangle(14, 370, 20, 100);
    public Rectangle paddle2;
    public static bool movesUp;
    public static bool movesDown;
    public static Graphics Draw;

    public static void DrawIt(PictureBox pb1)
    {
        Draw = pb1.CreateGraphics();
        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

        Draw.Clear(Color.Black);
        Draw.FillRectangle(sb, paddle1);
    }

    public static void CheckIfMoving()
    {
        if (movesUp == true)
        {
            paddle1.Y -= 1;
        }

        if (movesDown == true)
        {
            paddle1.Y += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the answers (:

Comment: Good luck getting a Timer to fire every 1ms. In all likelihood, it's going to fire at a considerably slower rate than 1ms. You can't rely on the accuracy or frequency of timers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, setting the Timer's interval to 1 produces an unnecessary overhead in this case. That's 1000 fps (well, it would be, if you could actually trust the Timer).

In DrawIt:

```
Draw = pb1.CreateGraphics();
SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
```

This, since DrawIt is called by the Timer's tick, recreates the Graphics, and the Brush, 1000 times, every second. Be careful about what you put in there.

Furtheremore, you shouldn't use the Picturebox's CreateGraphics method. Instead, override its OnPaint method, and call Refresh on it.

You can read more about this on [Bob Powell's Website](https://web.archive.org/web/20141006045615/http://bobpowell.net/creategraphics.aspx)

Comment: I've tried but it seems I cannot override it properly, should I override it inside the pong class and then call pb1.refresh() in drawit ?

Comment: You have to inherit from picturebox. However an easier approach would be to implement it's Paint event and put your code there.

Comment: outside of the PongGame class, I created a paint event ( picturebox1_Paint) but I don't know which parameters should I use inside the form method that initializes the component, i'd like to follow this approach to be able to use then invalidate() so i'll be forcing the picturebox to redraw itself. Would you please tell me the simplest possible code to achieve this ? It seems I simply cannot do it alone

Comment: http://www.pschierergraphics.com/professionalblog/?p=5 or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b12fcafd-3dce-4881-8f9a-407218bd8fb9/draw-on-picturebox might give you the idea

Comment: I think the issue is that the timer doesn't fire at the rate that the asker expects it to. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The timer makes no guarantee that it will fire at the interval that you specify. In fact it can, and does, fire at an interval longer than that which you specify.

Typically the actual interval of a timer will be related to the underlying system and hardware. It's not uncommon for timers on Windows to fire no more frequently than 20Hz.

If you are going to make a timer based game, then use the timer to give your game a pulse, a regular heartbeat. When the timer fires, use the amount of time since the last timer event to update the state. You'll need to use an accurate measure of time. The `Stopwatch` class should suffice.

You are also using the picture box incorrectly. This is an event driven control. You are expected to paint the scene in a handler for the `Paint` event of the picture box.

Comment: I can't really figure out how to make the moving paddle non-time based. Any input on this ? I'm new to programming and I'm used to think that a timer draws and clear things on screen, that's possibly why i haven't tought anything different... should I use an infinite for loop ?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you don't make it time based. Quite the opposite, it does indeed need to be related to the passing of real time. You just need to measure time accurately. A timer does not do that. `Stopwatch` does.